# Fade pictures in/out on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, this, mouseover

I have a series of pictures with a class of `.player__headshot` and right now it's fading out the image that's being moused over as opposed to the other 59 images in the series.

```
<div class="player player--goalie">
    <div class="player__headshot player--elder">
        <div class="picked is-active">
            <i class="fa fa-star" aria-hidden="true"></i>
        </div>
    </div>
    <p class="player__name">Brian Elder</p>
    <p class="player__position">Goalie</p>
</div>
```

```js
$(".player__headshot").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", 0.25);
});

$(".player__headshot").on("mouseout", function(){
    $(this).css("opacity", 1);
});
```

Comment: Because `this` refers to the element that is being moused over, the selector simply applies the event handler for all the class elements.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To fix this you can select all the `.player__headshot` elements and exclude the current one using `not()`, before fading them all back on `mouseleave`.

Also note that you can achieve this more effectively using `hover()`; it's shorter and uses `mouseenter` and `mouseleave` events instead:

```
$(".player__headshot").hover(function(){
    $(".player__headshot").not(this).css("opacity", 0.25);
}, function() {
    $(".player__headshot").css("opacity", 1);
});
```

Comment: Works great. I'm curious if you could elaborate more on your choice of a function inside another function, why this was the most efficient way of solving this problem?

Comment: Simply as the code is shorter and it uses `mouseenter` which only fires once when the mouse enters the attached element, instead of `mouseover` which fires continually for every pixel the mouse moves over the element. See http://api.jquery.com/hover for more info

Answer (score 0):

The code below will fade out everything that has the class player_headshot

```
$(".player__headshot").on("mouseover", function(){
    $(".player_headshot").css("opacity", 0.25);
});
```

If you want to keep the image you've moused over active, then you will need to change the class on that image to prevent it from being affected.

If you are using JQuery, perhaps remove the class from the selected image on mouseover or something like that.